# Grouping two graphs, one above the other, pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I want to organize two plots, where one should be above the other. My current code does it, but the distance between the graphs are very long. I would like to drastically reduce this distance.

My current code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        vertical sep=-4pt},   
        colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm) = (white);color(1cm) = (black)},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        }    
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line=none,
        axis z line=none,
        zmin = 0, zmax =0.1,  
        height=10cm,width=10cm 
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0}, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};

    \nextgroupplot[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    zmin = 0, zmax =1,       
    colorbar,    
    height=10cm,width=10cm
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};

    \addplot3 [only marks] file {data.txt}; 

    \end{groupplot}   
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

My current result is:
[image]

In addition, how can I make the color bar bigger such that it occupies all the height of the whole figure?

Edit 1:

The problem now is how to only show the lines of the axis that do not overlap with the above graph?

My current figure and code are:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        vertical sep=-40pt},   
        colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        }    
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line=none,
        axis z line=none,
        zmin = 0, zmax =0.1,  
        height=10cm,width=10cm, 
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0}, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};   

    \nextgroupplot[
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    zmin = 0, zmax =1,  
    height=10cm,width=10cm,
    colorbar,
    every colorbar/.append style={height=10.5cm}, colorbar shift/.append style={yshift=1.8cm},
    axis lines*=box
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};

    \addplot3 [colormap = {bw}{color(0cm)  = (black);color(1cm) = (white)}, scatter, only marks, scatter src=z, scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=black,
        fill=mapped color,
    }] file {data.txt}; 

    \end{groupplot}   
    %\end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Have you considered modifying the `vertical sep`? Regarding the colorbar question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126177/common-colorbar-for-groupplot

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, I have modified it, even to negative values. But, I did not success.

Comment: I noticed that you have `-4pt`, but what if you do `-40pt`? Or more.

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT., it worked. However, I would like to only show the lines of the axis that do not overlap with my graph above. Please see my Edit 1.

Comment: Don't know at the moment, `axis x line=bottom,   axis y line=left, axis z line=left` gets you almost there, but it also removes the z-axis on the right side.

Answer (score 2):

Your final problem is, that the flat plot is drawn first. Thus the 3d-plot overdraws it. This can be fixed by changing the order of the plots and adjusting `vertical sep` accordingly.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{filecontents*}{pgfplots-bw-data.txt}
2.17    0.001   0.82044815
2.17    0.002   0.82345825
2.17    0.004   0.82679255
2.17    0.008   0.83334715
2.17    0.016   0.84395915
2.17    0.032   0.8584953
2.21    0.001   0.77582165
2.21    0.003   0.78520505
2.21    0.009   0.80205985
2.21    0.027   0.83085105
2.24    0.001   0.7227885
2.24    0.002   0.73391615
2.24    0.005   0.7543979
2.24    0.015   0.78798745
2.24    0.003   0.74176635
2.24    0.009   0.77064805
2.24    0.027   0.81042375
2.26    0.001   0.66545585
2.26    0.003   0.7012046
2.26    0.005   0.721067
2.26    0.009   0.7447984
2.26    0.015   0.76715245
2.26    0.027   0.794177
2.27    0.001   0.62916195
2.27    0.003   0.6774642
2.27    0.009   0.72961785
2.27    0.027   0.7861086
2.28    0.001   0.5750828
2.28    0.003   0.65059675
2.28    0.005   0.6802631
2.28    0.009   0.7145367
2.28    0.015   0.74447695
2.28    0.027   0.7774403
2.29    0.001   0.51357255
2.29    0.002   0.581053
2.29    0.003   0.6173075
2.29    0.009   0.6972096
2.29    0.027   0.76793225
2.31    0.001   0.36997965
2.31    0.002   0.474415
2.31    0.003   0.53649295
2.31    0.009   0.6587164
2.31    0.016   0.70870255
2.31    0.027   0.7482423
2.31    0.05    0.7912395
2.34    0.001   0.2204104
2.34    0.002   0.316308
2.34    0.003   0.39256745
2.34    0.004   0.45240835
2.34    0.009   0.5883453
2.34    0.016   0.6590771
2.34    0.027   0.71444205
2.34    0.05    0.7690014
2.38    0.001   0.13286995
2.38    0.002   0.1828288
2.38    0.004   0.2980268
2.38    0.008   0.4507145
2.38    0.016   0.58417075
2.38    0.032   0.6833616
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\pgfdeclarelayer{top plot layer}
\pgfsetlayers{main,top plot layer}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt,
        vertical sep=-15.7cm},   
        colormap = {whiteblack}{color(0cm)  = (white);color(1cm) = (black)},
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        },
        x tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill,
            precision=2,
            /tikz/.cd
        }    
    ]

    \nextgroupplot[
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$,
        zmin = 0, zmax =1,  
        height=10cm,width=10cm,
        colorbar,
        every colorbar/.append style={height=10.5cm}, colorbar shift/.append style={yshift=1.8cm},
        axis lines*=box
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('pgfplots-bw-data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};

    \addplot3 [colormap = {bw}{color(0cm)  = (black);color(1cm) = (white)}, scatter, only marks, scatter src=z, scatter/use mapped color={
        draw=black,
        fill=mapped color,
    }] file {pgfplots-bw-data.txt}; 

    \nextgroupplot[
        axis x line=none,
        axis y line=none,
        axis z line=none,
        zmin = 0, zmax =0.1,  
        height=10cm,width=10cm, 
    ]

    \addplot3 [patch, shader=faceted interp, z filter/.code=\def\pgfmathresult{0}, patch table={triangles.txt}
    ] shell {echo "data=dlmread('pgfplots-bw-data.txt');
        tri=delaunay(data(:,1), data(:,2));
        dlmwrite('triangles.txt',tri-1,' ');
        disp(data)" | octave --silent};   

    \end{groupplot}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]